# Автоматическая подгрузка данных в ListView

Tags: android, listview, синтаксический-анализ

Всем привет.
Помогите, пожалуйста, долблюсь уже не один день...
Есть приложение, которое парсит JSON выводит все это дело в ListView. Используется GET запросы.
Нужно сделать следующее: при скроллинге вниз, доходя до конца списка, подгружались новые данные, а старые оставались. При каждой подгрузке будет использоваться запрос с разными параметрами. Так как я новичок, пожалуйста, прошу примеры давать)))
Заранее большое спасибо.
Даю код:

```
public class Test extends TabGroupActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String TAG_HREF="href";

    ListView list;
    HListAdapters adapter;
    ArrayList<homelist> homelist;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.index);

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        homelist = new ArrayList<homelist>();

        new ListAsynTask().execute("http://xxx.com/utf/auto.json? type=testdriveslist&offset");

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String href = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.href)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), webviews.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_HREF, href);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView lw, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    }

    public class ListAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Идет загрузка ... Ждемс...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params){
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "utf-8");

                    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(data);

                    for (int i=0; i<jsonarr.length();i++){
                        homelist hmlist = new homelist();
                        JSONObject c = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

                        hmlist.setTitle(c.getString("title"));
                        hmlist.setPictures(c.getString("picture"));
                        hmlist.setHref(c.getString("href"));
                        hmlist.setDate(c.getString("date"));

                        homelist.add(hmlist);
                    }

                    return true;
                }

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false){

            }else {

                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                adapter = new HListAdapters(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, homelist);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: [Хэшкод вопрос][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/360751/java-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5-g-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сделать интерфейс.
2. Добавить переменную типа itemsFromBottom, которая будет считать, сколько элементов осталось внизу и когда надо будет дернуть метод интерфейса из п.1, который загрузит новую пачку данных.
3. После загрузки данных добавить их в адаптер.
4. Если первые 3 пункта сложно - поискать на гитхабе любой из н-вариантов RefreshableListView.